# Ext.data.NodeInterface disabled attribute

Tags: javascript, extjs4

In ExtJs 3 there was an attribute "disabled" for TreeNode but in ExtJs 4 there is no any way to disable Tree Node (See Ext.data.NodeInterface configs).

Is there any way to disable TreeNode in ExtJs 4?

Answer (score 2):

I found [this plugin](https://github.com/zombeerose/NodeDisabled) useful for disabling nodes.

Comment: This plugin worked for me but I wonder has Sencha team added such an important property or not in the coming releases?